# Write a sql query not using correlated query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to rewrite a sql query not using correlated query. 
This is the query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT v.vendor_name, i.invoice_number, i.invoice_date, i.invoice_total  
FROM vendors v JOIN invoices i 
                ON i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
                AND i.invoice_date = (SELECT MIN(invoice_date)
                                      FROM invoices
                                      WHERE vendor_id = v.vendor_id)
```

I tried many ways, but I am always getting stuck with this query:
I don't know how to integrate columns invoice_number and invoice_total in this resultset.

```
SELECT  vendor_name, MIN(invoice_date) 
FROM  vendors JOIN invoices USING (vendor_id)
GROUP BY vendor_name
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the analytic function `rank`

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_name, invoice_number, invoice_date, invoice_total 
  FROM (SELECT v.vendor_name, 
               i.invoice_number, 
               i.invoice_date, 
               i.invoice_total,
               rank() over (partition by v.vendor_id
                                order by i.invoice_date asc) rnk
          FROM vendors v 
               JOIN invoices i 
                 ON i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

If you are looking to improve the performance of your query, I'd strongly question whether you need the `DISTINCT` since that forces an extra sort.  Frequently, developers use `DISTINCT` when they're really missing some join condition to properly eliminate the duplicate rows.

Comment: Thank you, Cave. It is a helpful orientation. I agree with you on using DISTINCT.